# Messenger chatbot webview closed event

Tags: webview, onbeforeunload, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am building a bot for messenger that supports webviews, and for some reasons, I have to be notified if the webview is closed (the user closes the webview from the `close` button or back on android).

Does any one knows any way to do it ?

I tried so far the `window.onbeforeunload` event, it works when I access the webview url directly in browser and try to refresh/close it, but when i access the webview, I can close it without any event fired.

The `MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser` closes the browser and emit success and error callbacks, it does not fire anything when the user closes the window

It is not an iframe issue, since i tried to put my UI in an iframe, then with a button to change the src of the iframe, i got the event fired.

I am using chatfuel as bot platform, spring boot for my backend, reactjs for my webviews.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For people looking for a solution, I ended up setting `websocket`and when the nested page opens, I `subscribe` to some event with some data, then I `unsubscribe` when needed.
I catch the close event when the websocket `disconnect` event is fired.

Comment: Were you able to find a better solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I used websocket